# IVP $y'=t^2-y^2+1, y(0)=a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Study the problem:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
y' &=& t^{2}-y^{2}+1\\ 
y(0) &=& a 
\end{array}\right.$$

a) Study the existence and uniqueness of solutions of the equation

b) Find the general solution

please help with this problem, as I can start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Existence of a unique solution.** It is an IVP for a first-order differential equation in the form $y'=f(t, y)$, $y(0)=a$, where $f(t, y)= t^2-y^2+1$. Since $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2y$ are continuous on any rectangle containing the point $(0, a)$ for all $a$, the IVP has a unique solution on some interval $-h<t<h$, with small $h>0$.

**Finding the general solution.** The DE is a Riccati type, so you must know a particular solution, which is already offered in the first answer as $f(t)=t$. To find other solutions (general solution) you can use the substitution $y=f+\frac{1}{u}$ to reduce the equation to a linear equation in $u$. Then you can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

an obvious solution is y=t

Let $y=t+f(t)$

$y'=1+f'=t²-t²-2t*f-f²+1$

$f'=-2t*f-f²$

Let $f=exp(-t²)*g(t)$

$f'=-exp(-t²)*2t*g+exp(-t²)*g'=-2t*exp(-t²)*g-exp(-2*t²)*g²$

$g'=-exp(-t²)*g²$

$-1/g=-\mbox{antiderivative}(exp(-t²))=C+erf(t)*\sqrt(\pi)/2$

$g=1/(C+erf(t)*\sqrt(\pi)/2)$

$y(t)=t+exp(-t²)/(C+erf(t)*\sqrt{\pi)/2}$

$y(0)=1/C$

$C=1/y(0)$